# The Visible property of a View control can only be set by setting the active View of a MultiView

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

I am encountering the following error when trying to set visibility of a view in my MultiView:

**"The Visible property of a View control can only be set by setting the active View of a MultiView."**

Here is the code:

MultiView1.SetActiveView(view);
view.Visible = false;

Also tried:
             MultiView1.Views[0].Visible = false;

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+Visible+property+of+a+View+control+can+only+be+set+by+setting+the+active+View+of+a+MultiView&oq=The+Visible+property+of+a+View+control+can+only+be+set+by+setting+the+active+View+of+a+MultiView&aqs=chrome..69i57.1519j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) you go....

Comment: Rick this just appears to be google search...I done one of those and have not come up with a solution as of yet, hence why I am posting this question to the community.

Comment: Try wrapping the `MultiView` inside of a `Panel` and set the Panel's visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I decided to take a different approach, which involved disabling the ability to even select the Views contained within a MultiView. The MultiView control that I am utilizing toggles between views VIA a RadioButtonList. I simply disabled whatever RadioButtonItem that was be restricted at the time, thus preventing users from accessing the view.